# How to design classes based on requirements or functionality

Tags: java, class, architecture, rule

I'm struggling with class design. Sometimes I think that all I have read about class organization, class diagram and class design can not apply to the concrete project. I want to create Snake game in Java using MVC or MVP architecture.

There are some requirements:

- The snake and food for snake should be drawn on screen
- It should be displayed current game score
- The snake should move using key arrow
- The food should be grouped so each group have some amount of point and color
- Game speed should be determined on score threshold

The question is how to organize classes (with methods and "all") according that requirements? Maybe someone have a book or link to suggest with guidance or examples.

Please could you share your rule of thumb for creating and organizing classes through this example?

Comment: This question might be suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. Have you tried any design / class diagram?

Comment: How would you solve it? Provide your suggestions and thoughts for further discussion.

Comment: 1/2 - Only thoughts, not a full answer and one solution amongst many. This is based on my experience, which is mostly anything but games. **M -** The snake and food would be in the `model` package and have properties such as `length` or `baseValue` (supposing you multiply the value according to the level). **C -** You would then have a controller which would determine the score, speed, (score multiplier), ... and control events when the snake gets food, eats itself, etc. And finally **V -** The classes which handles the graphics, input (keyboard arrows), and so on.

Comment: 2/2 - To make things easier, I recommend grouping each section in a separate package (all models in a `dto` or `model` package, controllers in a `controller` package and view in a `ui` package). Feel free to make subpackages of course. On larger projects, when using Maven, I find it sometimes even useful to make a separate Maven module for each of the three. Besides readability, keeping packages separated makes it easier to change: if you wish to switch from a web application to a client, you should hardly touch anything outside the `ui` package (well, web is bad example for this case...).

Comment: I would organize my code:in M would put classes for Snake and Food which would contain methods for design (color, possible movements, speed,..). In C would put all logic on movements, scoring and drawing objects. In V would put window design, snake design, food design and so on. But maybe I should organize code in MVC for all objects separately (MVC for: snake, food, window).

Comment: @LittlePanda - it's marginally on-topic for Programmers.  Generally speaking, the community prefers to see more of an attempt at the design than what this question presents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://yazalimbiraz.blogspot.com/2014/02/snake-game-written-in-java-full-source.html) of a simple Snake game clone in Java that you might refer to for ideas on how to structure things.

Since you ask for a book recommendation, I would recommend a book that helped me immensely in grasping object oriented analysis and design. It teaches you by solving real problems step by step. It is quite different as it does not follow the typical flow of technical books on the matter. It looks at gradually harder problems pointing at potential problems and explaining the important concepts along the way.

The book is called [Head First OOA&D](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfooad/). I recommend it because it is an easy (and sometimes even funny) read, with lots of samples in Java and on top of that, there is a game example in it. So be sure to check it out! Even outside the context of your problem I think you can benefit from it the way I did.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Plamen. The book you recommended is great. I'm feeling like all I have ever read are fitting together now. Somehow the common examples (Alice is a person, Polar bear is an animal, video store, consumer ...) from tutorials had not helped me to understand all. I'm going to work on these problems, maybe I should change books or examples.

Comment: @goRunToStack I know, right? I felt the same way back when I read the book! That is why I recommended it. Really glad to be of help! Tell me if you need more help.